# SQL BUG : The ROUND() method of SQL is not working properly - Issue in rounding off for some values

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, rounding

I am using a round method in my SQL proc and passing the rate parameter and ideally (as per the below code I am using) the round method should round off the value to 2 decimal places but it is acting weird.

But for other rate value, it is working fine and rounding off the number properly.

**SQL Server version :** SQL Server 8

**Code Snippet :**

```
ISNULL(round(rate,2),'')
```

Here, the value of rate is 3.025.

**Current output -** 3.02

**Expected Output -** 3.03  (After rounding off the value)

Also, I have observed that for the numbers (1.025 and 2.025), round method is also behaving the same way and not rounding it off as expected value.

**Question 1 :** Can anyone suggest, why this is happening and is there any existing bug at SQL server side similar to this ? I tried finding any bug but didn't reached close.

**Question 2 :** Is there any other way where I can replace the round method in the existing code, which can resolve this issue and also work properly for existing rate records ?

Comment: [I would wager your `rate` column is a `FLOAT` or `REAL` rather than a `DECIMAL`](https://dbfiddle.uk/cpw05b4R). `3.025` cannot be represented exactly in floating-point and the converted value is ever so slightly shy of `3.025`.

Comment: Yes, it is used as flaot in table. The data type of rate column is float.

Answer (score 3):

Is `RATE` a `FLOAT`? As pointed out by Jeroen 3.025 can't be perfectly represented by `FLOAT` and is getting rounded down. Perhaps changing the type to `DECIMAL` will generate the behavior you're looking for.

```
DECLARE @float FLOAT = 3.025
DECLARE @decimal DECIMAL(4,3) = 3.025
DECLARE @money MONEY = 3.025

PRINT @float                -- 3.025
PRINT @decimal              -- 3.025
PRINT @money                -- 3.03

PRINT ROUND(@float, 2)      -- 3.02
PRINT ROUND(@decimal, 2)    -- 3.030
PRINT ROUND(@money, 2)      -- 3.03
```

Comment: Yes, it is used as flaot in table. The data type of rate column is float. Let me try with decimal.